# Adding columns to GridView without project compilation with using of Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I want to use the EF 5.0 in my application (.NET 4.0 native application c#), but I cannot figure out how to solve the situation of adding new columns to datagrid without the project compilation and application update for all clients.

I can do this with my recent app behaviour like this

I keep the form columns in database. The grid is bind to the datatable into which I load data from  the database view. When user ask me to add new column, I change the view (if possible), add the new column to columns table and user is able to see the new column without any application overwriting.

I know the EF is created for the managing entities (so no way for dynamic properties), but is there any way how to use EF in same manner.

I am trying somehow implement MVC pattern, but I am maybe wrong.

I have the

- model - EF,
- controller - for the form
- Form class - with grid Dialog
- class for adding, editing

When user wants to add item to the grid in Form I am sending controller reference to the Dialog for creating (editing) new item. Controller has Property actual for the actual entity.

This can works for the static number of columns in grid. But If I want to have dynamic columns (generated from the database) then I have to keep the DataTable for the data from View and use EF only for dialog for adding, editing. But I would like to not combine this two attitudes.

Can you suggest me how to use only EF (and load data to some anonymous entity??) and also have the dynamic columns feature for grids?

Thank you for any advice